# Appending to Destination Table with Some Nullable Fields missing Fails in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've running a query where the query result needs to be appended (WRITE_APPEND) to a destination table. In the destination table there are several fields that are NULLABLE.

In my query result, some of the NULLABLE fields from destination table are missing.

My query fails with following error:

```
    Query Failed
    Error: Invalid schema update. Field age is missing in new schema
    Job ID: job_5761xOBwaQbQPIi6wD9dqy-Cdzk
```

Seems like a unnecessary limitation especially given that I can do the same thing via JSON uploads. Is there any work around to this?

Thanks,
Navneet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've got a fix for this issue, it got re-prioritized behind some other work, but we'll likely get it in soon, hopefully by early next week.

Comment: awesome.. that will be great!

Comment: Hi Jordan, I'm trying the fix the Fh. suggested. Select null as a_field, etc. (see job: job_57jKlRYSmsQ2j9AwKX36akiRImE ). However it gives me the following error. Query Failed Error: Invalid schema update. Field age has changed type . Can you please suggest what's the right way to save to destination table when the query result are missing some fields that are nullable in the destination table. Thanks a lot. - navneet

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting feature request. In the meantime, could you manually add the missing columns as nulls to the query, so it doesn't fail?

Something like this:

```
SELECT word, null AS a_field
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
LIMIT 10
```

(note that column `a_field` has only nulls)

Comment: Yes. I know this will work. Would appreciate the feature in future.

Comment: Jordan saves the day :)

Comment: Not so quick.. Now I get a different error: Query Failed
Error: Invalid schema update. Field age has changed type
Job ID: job_57jKlRYSmsQ2j9AwKX36akiRImE

Comment: haven't been able to reproduce - more context? (or reply to Jordan's answer to get him notified)

Comment: sure.. are you able to see the job? job_57jKlRYSmsQ2j9AwKX36akiRImE Here's the query: SELECT  user as name, null as age FROM [ziptrips.tempTable2];  The destination table has two columns: name:string, age:integer. I get the following error: Query Failed
Error: Invalid schema update. Field age has changed type
Job ID: job_OepNVE3587egdJOSp2DYAJB8n0I

Comment: Please add more context. I can help answer much faster this way. Job ids are better for bugs that get reported to the team, but for general queries support, prefer pasting the actual query and preferably sample data - that way a lot more people can answer these questions.

Comment: The null default data type is not the same as the data type of the field in your schema. You need to define its data type. try SELECT user as name, integer(null) as age FROM [ziptrips.tempTable2];